# How to get font path from font name [python]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

My aim is to get the font path from their common font name and then use them with `PIL.ImageFont`.

I got the names of all installed fonts by using `tkinter.font.families()`, but I want to get the full path of each font so that I can use them with `PIL.ImageFont`.
Is there any other way to use the common font name with `ImageFont.truetype()` method?

Comment: Fonts are usually kept in a system directory that depends on your OS, which is to say that there's not a one-size-fits-all solution. Does [this article](https://www.lifewire.com/locate-font-files-1074150) help at all?

Comment: Tkinter doesn't have the ability to give you the path to a font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you really want - but here is a way to get a list of the full path to all the fonts on your system and their names and weights:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.font_manager
from PIL import ImageFont

# Iterate over all font files known to matplotlib
for filename in matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(): 
    # Avoid these two trouble makers - don't know why they are problematic
    if "Emoji" not in filename and "18030" not in filename:
        # Look up what PIL knows about the font
        font = ImageFont.FreeTypeFont(filename)
        name, weight = font.getname()
        print(f'File: {filename}, fontname: {name}, weight: {weight}')
```

**Sample Output**

```
File: /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/NotoSansLepcha-Regular.ttf, fontname: Noto Sans Lepcha, weight: Regular
File: /System/Library/Fonts/ZapfDingbats.ttf, fontname: Zapf Dingbats, weight: Regular
File: /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Zapfino.ttf, fontname: Zapfino, weight: Regular
File: /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/NotoSansMultani-Regular.ttf, fontname: Noto Sans Multani, weight: Regular
File: /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/NotoSansKhojki-Regular.ttf, fontname: Noto Sans Khojki, weight: Regular
File: /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/Mishafi Gold.ttf, fontname: Mishafi Gold, weight: Regular
File: /System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/NotoSansMendeKikakui-Regular.ttf, fontname: Noto Sans Mende Kikakui, weight: Regular
File: /System/Library/Fonts/MuktaMahee.ttc, fontname: Mukta Mahee, weight: Regular
File: /Users/mark/Library/Fonts/JetBrainsMonoNL-Italic.ttf, fontname: JetBrains Mono NL, weight: Italic
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another way to do it

Dependencies:

- [FindSystemFontsFilename](https://pypi.org/project/FindSystemFontsFilename/)
- [fontTools](https://pypi.org/project/fonttools/)

```py
from enum import IntEnum
from find_system_fonts_filename import get_system_fonts_filename
from fontTools.ttLib.tables._n_a_m_e import NameRecord
from fontTools.ttLib.ttFont import TTFont


class NameID(IntEnum):
    COPYRIGHT = 0
    FAMILY_NAME = 1
    SUBFAMILY_NAME = 2
    UNIQUE_ID = 3
    FULL_NAME = 4
    VERSION_STRING = 5
    POSTSCRIPT_NAME = 6
    TRADEMARK = 7
    MANUFACTURER = 8
    DESIGNER = 9
    DESCRIPTION = 10
    VENDOR_URL = 11
    DESIGNER_URL = 12
    LICENSE_DESCRIPTION = 13
    LICENSE_URL = 14
    TYPOGRAPHIC_FAMILY_NAME = 16
    TYPOGRAPHIC_SUBFAMILY_NAME = 17
    MAC_FULL_NAME = 18
    SAMPLE_TEXT = 19
    POSTSCRIPT_CID_FINDFONT_NAME = 20
    WWS_FAMILY_NAME = 21
    WWS_SUBFAMILY_NAME = 22
    LIGHT_BACKGROUND = 23
    DARK_BACKGROUND = 24
    VARIATIONS_PREFIX_NAME = 25


def sort_naming_table(names: list[NameRecord]) -> list[NameRecord]:
    """
    Parameters:
        names (List[NameRecord]): Naming table
    Returns:
        The sorted naming table
    """

    def is_english(name: NameRecord) -> bool:
        return (name.platformID, name.langID) in ((1, 0), (3, 0x409))

    PLATFORM_ID_APPLE_UNICODE = 0
    PLATFORM_ID_MACINTOSH = 1
    PLATFORM_ID_ISO = 2
    PLATFORM_ID_MICROSOFT = 3
    PLATFORM_ID_ORDER = [
        PLATFORM_ID_MICROSOFT,
        PLATFORM_ID_APPLE_UNICODE,
        PLATFORM_ID_MACINTOSH,
        PLATFORM_ID_ISO,
    ]

    return sorted(
        names,
        key=lambda name: (
            PLATFORM_ID_ORDER.index(name.platformID),
            name.nameID,
            name.platEncID,
            -is_english(name),
            name.langID,
        ),
    )


def get_name_by_id(names: list[NameRecord], nameID: int, ) -> str:
    """
    Parameters:
        names (List[NameRecord]): Naming table
        nameID (int): ID of the name you search
    Returns:
        The decoded name
    """

    names = list(filter(lambda name: name.nameID == nameID, names))
    names = sort_naming_table(names)

    for name in names:
        try:
            name_str = name.toUnicode()
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            continue

        return name_str


def main():
    fonts_filename = get_system_fonts_filename()

    for filename in fonts_filename:
        font = TTFont(filename, fontNumber=0)
        print(f"File: {filename}, family name: {get_name_by_id(font['name'].names, NameID.FAMILY_NAME)}")

        # Handle TTC font
        if hasattr(font.reader, "numFonts") and font.reader.numFonts > 1:
            for index in range(1, font.reader.numFonts):
                font = TTFont(filename, fontNumber=index)
                print(f"File: {filename}, family name: {get_name_by_id(font['name'].names, NameID.FAMILY_NAME)}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```